How to tell docs.rs not to build crate dependencies?
I have a problem with building docs on docs.rs for my crate molar. This crate has several dependencies, which are wrappers over C/C++ libraries and they use complex CMake setup to build including fetching header libraries from github (for example molar_powersasa). The docs.rs build container has no access to the network, so the build fails.
Is there a way to tell docs.rs not to build such dependencies? If not, what is the simplest way of solving this problem? I read about custom docker containers for docs.rs, but I have zero experience with docker and I'd like to avoid this if possible.

The build scripts of your wrapper dependencies could switch on std::env::var("DOCS_RS").is_ok() to not actually build the C/C++ libraries but instead to use some internal shim that emits sensible documentation?  Or else you could build and host the docs elsewhere (configured in your Cargo.toml so that crates.io points at it).
